# mmenu: sliding menu clears title on sublevels

Tags: javascript, html, title, slide, mmenu

I am trying to use **mmenu** for an application and everything is going great, except the menu title.

As for now, the menu has 1 parent-item, 'Menu A', and the menu hierarchy is the following:

- Menu A

  - A1

    - A1a
  - A2

    - A2a
    - A2b

First level ('Menu A') slides into Second level (new menu with 'A1' and 'A2'). Third level is vertical and is expanded under its parent. More graphical detail comes up next.

First step (sorry, I'm only allowed to post 2 links, so I removed this screenshot): The initial state of the menu is the parent item A, with no title. **OK**

[Second step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNBcJ.png): When I click the parent, the title changes to 'Menu A' and the children are loaded into the menu. **OK**

[Third step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVSGy.png): Lastly, when I click on a child loaded from the previous step, the title disappears, and I have no clue why. **NOT OK** Any ideas?

Here follows the javascript and HTML code of my menu:

```js
$("#navigation").mmenu(
  { // options
  "extensions": [
    "border-full",
    "multiline",
    "iconbar"
  ],

  navbar: {
    title: ''
  },
  navbars: [
    {
    position  : 'top',
    content   : ['prev','title']
    }
  ],

  },

  { // configuration
  offCanvas: {
    pageSelector: "#wrapper",
    wrapPageIfNeeded: false
   }
  }
);
```

```html
<nav class="sort-pages modify-pages" id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li class="">
      <span>
        <span>Menu A</span>
      </span>
      <ul class="child-menu" id="sub-0">
        <li class="">
          <span>
            <span>A1</span>
          </span>
          <ul class="child-menu mm-vertical" id="sub-sub-1">
            <li class="MenuTransactionLink">
              <a href="#" link="a1a">
                <span>A1a</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <span>
            <span>A2</span>
          </span>
          <ul class="child-menu mm-vertical" id="sub-sub-2">
            <li class="MenuTransactionLink">
              <a href="#" link="a2a">
                <span>A2a</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="MenuTransactionLink">
              <a href="#" link="a2b">
                <span>A2b</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I am happy to help with more details, if needed.

---

Following the developer's Github issue list, i found this in particular:

> I think this is because "vertical" panels (all panels when you use slidingSubmenus: false) do not have a navbar. I'll see if I can do something about that.
>   For now, I guess it's either slidingSubmenus or no title.

(source: github.com/FrDH/jQuery.mmenu/issues/535)

I even tried forcing it using Javascript, by binding an 'on click' event to the menu items:

`$('nav a.mm-fullsubopen').on('click', function (e){ 
    var title = $('#navigation').find('.mm-title')[0]; 
    title.text = $('#' + $('.mm-opened.mm-panel.mm-highest').attr('id')).find('.mm-title').text(); 
    $(title).removeClass('mm-hidden')
});`

This works for a few miliseconds, until the mmenu plugin overwrites the title with an empty string (see link from third step above). It must have some kind of event that fires after this one, making mine completely useless.

How can I do a workaround to make this behaviour possible?